# Call managed C++ functions from C#

Tags: c#, pointers, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I have an managed C++ Wrapper for unmanaged C++ code and it's necessary to use some pointer parameters into the methods!

What's the best way in C# to call this wrapper functions (I tryed it with reference parameter in the managed code and create the pointer and call then the unmanaged code)?

Example:

```
// c++/managed
Uint32 someMethod(int &value);

Uint32 Wrapper::someMethod(int &value)
{
    int *valuePtr = &value;
    return unmanagedObj->someMethod(valuePtr);
}

// c++/unmanaged
Uint32 someMethod(int *value);

Uint32 UnmanagedClass::someMethod(int *value)
{
    ...
}
```

I use the managed C++ wrapper with "add reference" in VS2008, but when I call someMethod
in C# there are only a pointer instead of reference?!

```
// c#
// e.g. value conversion to C++ pointer
...
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
wrapper.someMethod(ref value); // should work but here we have an C++ pointer
// and not a reference ?!?!
```

Thank you for any tips!

greets

Comment: Managed C++ is officially called C++CLI, so I retagged that.

Comment: ok sorry! It has been overlooked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `int%`, which is the correct syntax for C++CLI references and called a [tracking reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
Uint32 Wrapper::someMethod(int %value)
```

Comment: Thanks (I'm already wondering that reference = pointer ;-) ) !